# Java ACM JTF Package

Tags: java

I have a doubt in the below piece of code. I wanted to know why does the code compile and run correctly even though main method is not present?

```
import acm.program.*;  

public class HelloConsole extends ConsoleProgram {  

   public void run() {  
      println("hello, world");  
   }    
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because consoleprogram extends the class program which contains a main method.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design of the ACM program classes.  See the [javadocs](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts//jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/package-summary.html):

> The conventional pattern of use
>   associated with the acm.program
>   package moves students away from the
>   imperative style of public static void
>   maininto a more pedagogically
>   defensible framework in which students
>   are always working in the context of
>   an object.

In this case you override the init/run methods as opposed to writing a main method.